# get the count of each distinct value in "Multiple" columns

Tags: mysql, sql

so lets say I have

```
| id | value |
--------------
|  1 |   A   |
|  2 |   B   |
|  3 |   B   |
|  4 |   A   |
|  5 |   A   |
```

and then run the following SQL statment

```
SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM test2 GROUP BY value
```

I would get  A: 3 and B: 2

Great, but what If I wanted to combine from multiple columns

```
| id | value | Value2 | Value 3|
---------------------------------
|  1 |   A   |   A    |    A   |
|  2 |   B   |   A    |    B   |
|  3 |   B   |   B    |    B   |
|  4 |   A   |   A    |    A   |
|  5 |   A   |   B    |    A   |
```

in the above A:9  B:6.  Currently I can just run the above statment 3 times, and then add the value on the php side. But I figured there might be a neat little trick to get it all done in 1 statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the three columns into single column using `Union all` then find the count of each group in outer query. Try this.

```
SELECT value,
       Count(value)
FROM   (SELECT value AS value FROM test2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT value2 FROM test2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT value3 FROM test2)a
GROUP  BY value
```

Comment: I seem to get Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'

Comment: Spot on, Ill need to teach myself some more on unions it looks like. Thank  you! ill mark as answer as soon as it lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

At first you can `COUNT` values for each separate column and group, then combine results with `UNION ALL`  and at last `SUM` them for each group.

```
SELECT `num`, SUM(`num`)
FROM (
    SELECT value, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM test2 GROUP BY value
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value2, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM test2 GROUP BY value2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT value3, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM test2 GROUP BY value3
) GROUP BY `num`
```