# How to get the count of each distinct value in Multiple columns and get the result in separate columns?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite

I need the following table to be queried to get the result given below the table.

Table:

```
----------------------------------
| Name  |  Age   |  slot         |
|-------|--------|---------------|
|A      |20      | 1             |
|B      |30      | 2             |  
|C      |30      | 1             |                
|D      |20      | 1             |                
|E      |40      | 2             |                
|F      |40      | 3             |
|G      |50      | 3             |
----------------------------------
```

Result:

```
-------------------------------------------
|Age   |Age_Count     |Slot    |Slot_Count|
-------------------------------------------
|20    | 2            |1       |3         |
-------------------------------------------
|30    | 2            |2       |2         |
-------------------------------------------
|40    | 2            |3       |2         |
-------------------------------------------
|50    | 1            |
-----------------------
```

While searching stackoverflow i found [this question for single column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053902/sql-how-to-get-the-count-of-each-distinct-value-in-a-column) question and there is [this link for multiple columns] ([get the count of each distinct value in "Multiple" columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28133875/get-the-count-of-each-distinct-value-in-multiple-columns)) question. The answers from the second link (for the multiple coulmn's distinct count) is displayed under a single column and my requirement is i guess quite different from the answers posted there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the `slot` column in your result table? How should that be calculated?

Comment: It is any slot alloted to the ids. The calculation for it is same as for the age. It will calculate distinct slots and give me the number of it. e.g. i have 3 slots named slot 1, 2 slots named slot 2. so the result table is showing distinct slots under slot field and their count under slot_count.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is kind of odd. Are you sure you want that?

If so, this may help:

```
SET @x:=0,@y:=0,@m:=0,@n:=0;
SELECT 
    DISTINCT age,age_count, slot,slot_count 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        age, age_count, slot, slot_count
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            @x:=@x + 1 AS aid, age, COUNT(*) age_count
        FROM
            slots
        GROUP BY age
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            @y:=@y + 1 AS sid, slot, COUNT(*) slot_count
        FROM
           slots
        GROUP BY slot
    ) s ON a.aid = s.sid

    UNION

    SELECT 
        age, age_count, slot, slot_count
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            @m:=@m + 1 AS aid, slot, COUNT(*) slot_count
        FROM
           slots
        GROUP BY slot
    ) a 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT 
            @n:=@n + 1 AS sid, age, COUNT(*) age_count
        FROM
            slots
        GROUP BY age
    ) s ON a.aid = s.sid
) a
```

If you know for sure that you have more unique ages than unique slots , or opposite, you can get ride of messy union.