# How to get the number of occurrence of each distinct value of GROUP CONCAT (php,mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I know this is something very easy to do but i have not gotten the correct way to do it.  i found something [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30423433/how-to-get-the-count-of-each-distinct-value-in-multiple-columns-and-get-the-resu) but different from what i need and no active contribution yet.  Someone kindly assist.

I have a table like this

```
name |status
-------------
mike |yes
mike |yes
mike |no
mike |ney
john |no
john |ney
john |yes
```

i want to output something like this

```
name |status           |total
------------------------------
mike |yes-2,no-1,ney-1 | 4
john |yes-1,no-1,ney-1 | 3
```

I tried using GROUP_CONCAT like this

```
    result = mysql_query("SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT status) AS status 
FROM table GROUP BY name ");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $st[] = $row['status'];
            $status=explode(",",$row['status']);
            $total = count($status);
            echo $row['name']."|".$row['status']."|".$total."<br><br>"; }
```

I would like to get the number of each distinct `$row['status']` and if possible, a better way of arriving at `$total`.

**EDIT1**

```
name | yes | no | ney | total
------------------------------
mike |2    |1   |1    | 4
john |1    |1   |1    | 3
```

This second output was achieved [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090138/improve-on-how-to-get-the-number-of-occourence-for-each-distinct-value-of-group/31090337#31090337)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use php as you can use pure SQL to get the desired result set:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(totalPerStatus) AS status, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE name = t.name) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT name,      
         CONCAT(status, '-', COUNT(*)) AS totalPerStatus            
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY name, status ) t
GROUP BY name;
```

The grouping by `name, status` performed in the sub-query gives you the count per 'status' per 'name'. Using `CONCAT` produces the following result set:

```
name    totalPerStatus
-----------------------
john    ney-1
john    no-1
john    yes-1
mike    ney-1
mike    no-1
mike    yes-2
```

The outer query uses `GROUP_CONCAT` on `totalPerStatus` to produce the required result set.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/740d6/13)

Comment: I trust your Answer should work but pls check, I think i have a syntax error. `$result = mysql_query("SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(totalPerStatus) AS status (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE name = t.name) AS total FROM (SELECT name,CONCAT(status, '-', COUNT(*)) AS totalPerStatus FROM table GROUP BY name, status ) t GROUP BY name; ") ;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
echo $row['name']."-".$row['status']."-".$row['totalPerStatus']."-".$row['total']; }`

Comment: @scylla There's a comma missing after 'AS status'

Comment: SQL works great but my echo command returns fatal error as i try to verify the data output in each $row. i.e `$row['name'], $row['status'], $row['totalPerStatus']`. how do i go about this? Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in

Comment: @scylla I'm afraid I can't help you on this. It's been at least ten year since I last wrote some code in php :(

Comment: twas an error on my part. was using mysql_fetch_object instead of mysql_fetch_array while fiddling with the code. This is great.

Comment: But I love to restructure my outcome this way Pls Check the question edit. could not get my fiddle to work.

Comment: @scylla Well, that's a different question. I think you should write a new post.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81714/discussion-between-scylla-and-giorgos-betsos).