# Improve on How to get the number of occourence for each distinct Value of Group Concat Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am trying to fiddle around this answer to get a more improved output. 
I have a table like this

```
name |status
-------------
mike |yes
mike |yes
mike |no
mike |ney
john |no
john |ney
john |yes
```

to output something like this

```
name |status           |total
------------------------------
mike |yes-2,no-1,ney-1 | 4
john |yes-1,no-1,ney-1 | 3
```

Someone suggested this answer that works great.

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(totalPerStatus) AS status, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE name = t.name) AS total
FROM (
  SELECT name,      
         CONCAT(status, '-', COUNT(*)) AS totalPerStatus            
  FROM mytable
  GROUP BY name, status ) t
GROUP BY name;
```

But I want to improve on this output to get something like this

```
name | yes | no | ney | total
------------------------------
mike |2    |1   |1    | 4
john |1    |1   |1    | 3
```

Comment: Are `yes`, `no` and `ney` the only options you expect, or should this be generic for any combination?

Comment: Yes. Just `yes`, `no` and `ney`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption (confirmed in the comments) that the only three statuses are `yes`, `no` and `ney`, the simplest thing may be to just `count` conditional `case` statements:

```
SELECT   name,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'yes' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS yes,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'no' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS no,
         COUNT(CASE status WHEN 'ney' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ney,
         COUNT(*) AS total
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the subquery in the `select`.  You can get the count for each status and then aggregate that:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(totalPerStatus) AS status, 
       SUM(cnt) as Total
FROM (SELECT name,      
             CONCAT(status, '-', COUNT(*)) AS totalPerStatus,
             COUNT(*) as cnt            
      FROM mytable
      GROUP BY name, status
     ) t
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: This returns same output as before. check it out. It doesnt return seperate column for the options and total.

Comment: @scylia . . . I read "to output something like this" and thought you were looking for this output as well.

Comment: Gratitude. Twas just what i wanted to improve on. but the output of your suggestion was perfect